# BEGIN-END inside BEGIN TRY- END TRY

Tags: sql-server

I try to use `BEGIN-END` liberally. Is there a point in using this contruct in this context?:

```
BEGIN TRY           
    BEGIN

         --do x
         --do y  

    END 
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    BEGIN

         --do z

    END                                                 
END CATCH;
```

Or is it just as safe to use the following?:

```
BEGIN TRY           

         --do x
         --do y  

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

         --do z

END CATCH;
```

Comment: hmmmm - this is a specific, generic question. It might be obvious to some readers what the answer is but I can't see why that means it should be downvoted? Maybe it is a repeat of a previous question - if so why hasn't the mystery down-voter said what the previous question is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `begin try ... end try` block is a complete block in itself, there is no point in having an extra `begin ... end` inside it.

Use `begin ... end` for statements that aren't blocks in themselves, for example `if`:

```
if ... begin
  ...
end else begin
  ...
end
```

Comment: I suspect you would have given reasons if you'd marked the question down..I ask a lot of questions and get a bit annoyed when they get marked down with no explanation

Comment: @whytheq: Yes, if I had voted it down, I would have given a reason. I hate it myself when someone votes down without saying what they think is wrong.